# Multitenant token Validation using OpenidConnect

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I have a multitenant aad app for which token validation needs to be done. I have access to the token in 'TokenValidated' event handler. For now, I have the property 'ValidateIssuer' set to true. Looking online, I noticed a lot of places this property is set to false for multitenant applications and there is a mention of custom validation. Can someone tell me what extra token validation needs to be done for multitenant applications? Examples will be helpful.

I have read about ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, but don't know if that applies in my scenario since we do not restrict any specific tenants.

Thanks

-Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/03/03/principles-of-token-validation/) a great article on token validation you may find helpful. The [Azure AD Token Claims Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims) is also extremely useful.

Issuer validation is used to indicate the sts that issued the token and the tenant for which it was issued. So in the case of a multi-tenant app, you may choose to turn off issuer validation as to not limit any tenants from signing in. In the single tenant or n tenant case, you can use this to only allow tokens from specific tenants.

The other validation necessary is signature validation.  Doing this ensures the token was actually minted from Azure AD (issuing authority) and not fabricated from some nefarious source.

Comment: So, in my case it seems I primarily need to do a claims and signature validation. Is there any sample code you can point me to for doing that? Also doesn't OpenIdConnect validate claims automatically when user logs in?

Comment: I would like to also add this sample app on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect. Check out especially this part: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L62-L70. The middleware can do the signature validation for you, but you'll also want to check the token is for a tenant that has actually gone through the onboarding process.

Comment: @juunas This is preciselywhat I have. Except that I am not storing any users/issuers in a db, since a user from any tenant can login. I am assuming the middleware is already taking care of signature and claims validation since we are in the 'SecurityTokenValidated' event handler. Is that correct? I am not sure what extra checks are needed.